# 1953 version of Scrabble includes 4 wooden dice - why?

Tags: scrabble

I have acquired a 1953 version of Scrabble.  Included with the usual 100 wooden tiles are 4 wooden dice.  Each face of the dice  has the dots imprinted using one of these 3 colors; red, green or black.  I am not familiar with Scrabble using dice.  How do the dice get incorporated into the game both in use & scoring?

Comment: Hmm, neither http://www.donaldsauter.com/scrabble-dating.htm (history of Scrabble hardware) or http://www.donaldsauter.com/scrabble-rules.htm (history of Scrabble rules) mentions anything about dice. Is it possible that the dice came from a different game?

Comment: Perhaps a better question would be, "Did Scrabble's 1953 edition include 4 wooden dice?", or somesuch. :)

Answer (score 13):

Sounds like 4 stowaways from a game of [Kismet](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2581/kismet), which was Yahtzee with green, red and black spots on dice.

Comment: Kismet was my first thought, too. What a fun game :-)

Comment: I certainly appreciate your suggestions.  I am not familiar with Kismet  but did look at  Kismet images of dice used in this game. Kismet dice have  different colors used on different numbers on the die itself ( one dice has different colors used for the dots).  Each of the 4 dice that I have found in the 1953 Scrabble game uses only 1 color i.e. one dice has all green spots for its numbers, etc.  The wooden dice match the wooden scrabble tiles - the wood type used and the finish applied is the same.  These dice look like they belong to Scrabble, although maybe they don't.